# How to use BSTS package

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, bayesian, mcmc

I'm trying to forecast VOO monthly stock price using BSTS and this is what I currently have.

The plots for predicting vs test data is as follow:
[image]
As you can see the more horizontal line is the predicted one and it's not that good. Anyway to make it better?
[The data i got is from here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VOO/history?period1=1283990400&period2=1682035200&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo&includeAdjustedClose=true)

This is my current code:

```
install.packages("bsts")
library("bsts")


# Import data
voo_data <- read.csv("voo.csv")
head(voo_data)

# Convert the 'Date' column to a Date object
voo_data$Date <- as.Date(voo_data$Date)

# Sort the data by date
voo_data <- voo_data[order(voo_data$Date),]

# Train and test data
voo_train <- voo_data[seq(1,141),]
voo_train_ts <- ts(voo_train$Close, start=c(2010, 9), end=c(2022, 5), frequency=12)


voo_test <- voo_data[seq(142,151),]
voo_test_ts <- ts(voo_test$Close, start=c(2022, 6), end=c(2023, 3), frequency=12)


# Set the parameters for the bsts model
params <- list(niter = 10000, nseasons = 12)


ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), voo_train_ts)
ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, voo_train_ts, nseasons= 12)

# Build the bsts model
model <- bsts(voo_train_ts, state.specification = ss, niter = params$niter)


plot(model)
plot(model, "components")
res <- residuals(model)
mse <- mean(res^2)
rmse <- sqrt(mse)

# Plot residual
plot(res[,1], type = "l", ylab = "Residuals", main = "Residuals of BSTS Model for VOO Stock Prices")



forecast <- predict(model, horizon = 10)
plot(forecast)
ts.plot(voo_test_ts,forecast$mean)
```